# IntelliJ IDEA Run applications

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Excuse me, the Run applications of IntelliJ IDEA in the picture below have questions about variables.
After the Run applications are running, will they save the previously executed variables like the JShell console of IntelliJ IDEA, and they can be used in the next execution?

[image]

I want to know whether Run applications has such a function, or only JShell console can do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the arrow present just after `Current File`, you will find an option called `Edit Configurations`. There you can add your own variables for running your application. And yes, you can save your configuration using the `Save TEST_CLASS_NAME Configuration`.

[image]